# Serializer doesnt return id after create object

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to read the id field along with the additional data I send to the serializer, without disrupting the structure I have established for the two models I have created.
When I use modelserializer, there is a problem with additional data.
In the definition I made in this way, the id value is not returned, and I do not understand why.I also avoided using a nested structure.

I have two model as Chat and message.

```
class Chat(models.Model):
    chat_fields = ...


class Message(models.Model):
    chat = models.ForeignKey(Chat)
    message_field = ...
```

While creating a Chat object, I also need to create a message object, so I defined it like this instead of modelserializer, but it didn't return an id object after create conversation object, I could not understand this and I was very confused about this. I have the following definition in the view.

```
class CreateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    chat_fields...
    message_fields...
```

I use the view structure as standard, there are some services I added, but I only read the chat and message data I get from the serializer there.

```
class CreateView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                       mixins.ListModelMixin,
                       mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                       GenericViewSet):
    ....

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I tried to use modelserializer but it didn't work as when I expected.

Comment: Well it doesn't create anything, since... what would creating mean for a simple serializer? A `ModelSerializer` is "backed" by a model, so can write to the database, a simple serializer is backed by *nothing*.

Comment: simple serializer is only validating the data not creating any record in the database. to create a record in the database you need to create ORM query. and an alternative solution is that you can use a model serializer.